# Unable to apply line drawing and filling it animation in svg

Tags: html, css, svg

I want a line drawing animation and I tried to follow some youtube tutorials and I want something like this https://codepen.io/shshaw/pen/Hjyio which first draw the logo then fills it. Till now I tried this but failed miserably. I searched every other question on stack overflow question everyone tell about only line drawing animation but I want to fill it also.
Also I don't draw any line animation.

Any suggestion of where I am wrong and also adding px unit don't help at all ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>SVG</title>
    <style>
        path {
            stroke:#000;
            stroke-dasharray: 2500;
            stroke-width:3;
            animation: my_animation 100s;
        }

        @keyframes my_animation{
            0%{
                stroke-dashoffset: 0;
            }
            50%{
                stroke-dashoffset: 2500;
            }
            100%{
                stroke-dashoffset: 0;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewBox="0 0 640 640" width="640" height="640"><defs><path d="M479 320L639 0L318.99 0L-1 0L158.98 320L318.99 640L479 320Z" id="aLRf203Rm"></path><path d="M301.47 203.41L401.95 0L200.97 0L0 0L100.48 203.41L200.97 406.83L301.47 203.41Z" id="a1ManYbeyy"></path></defs><g><g><use xlink:href="#aLRf203Rm" opacity="1" fill="#ff0043" fill-opacity="1"></use><g><use xlink:href="#aLRf203Rm" opacity="1" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#ff0043" stroke-width="1" stroke-opacity="1"></use></g></g><g><use xlink:href="#a1ManYbeyy" opacity="1" fill="#00ffda" fill-opacity="1"></use><g><use xlink:href="#a1ManYbeyy" opacity="1" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#00ffda" stroke-width="1" stroke-opacity="1"></use></g></g></g></svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use your keyframes.  In this example, I have made the stroke animation run from time 0% to 80%. Then I make the fill fade in using `fill-opacity` from time 80% to 100%.

```css
path {
  stroke:#000;
  stroke-dasharray: 2072;
  stroke-width:3;
  animation: my_animation 4s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  fill: red;
}

@keyframes my_animation{
  0%{
    stroke-dashoffset: 2072;
    fill-opacity: 0;
  }
  80%{
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    fill-opacity: 0;
  }
  100%{
    fill-opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewBox="0 0 640 640" width="640" height="640"><defs><path d="M479 320L639 0L318.99 0L-1 0L158.98 320L318.99 640L479 320Z" id="aLRf203Rm"></path><path d="M301.47 203.41L401.95 0L200.97 0L0 0L100.48 203.41L200.97 406.83L301.47 203.41Z" id="a1ManYbeyy"></path></defs><g><g><use xlink:href="#aLRf203Rm" opacity="1" fill="#ff0043" fill-opacity="1"></use><g><use xlink:href="#aLRf203Rm" opacity="1" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#ff0043" stroke-width="1" stroke-opacity="1"></use></g></g><g><use xlink:href="#a1ManYbeyy" opacity="1" fill="#00ffda" fill-opacity="1"></use><g><use xlink:href="#a1ManYbeyy" opacity="1" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#00ffda" stroke-width="1" stroke-opacity="1"></use></g></g></g></svg>
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/shshaw/pen/Hjyio it's not showing animation like this